# How I do I convert WebElement element into a String, so that I am able to pass it inside driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I cannot figure out how do I convert my `WebElement` element into a String so that I can pass inside `driver.findElement(By.xpath(element))` ?

For Example :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(somexpath));

public void clickOnButton(WebElement element){

    String xpath = element.toString();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
}
```

I am getting exceptions

Comment: What is the point of this? Inside your function, why not just use `element.click();`?

Answer (score 0):

Make a String and store the value of your xpath in it and then use that string in the findElement method.
For example:

```
String elementPath = "xpathExpresssion";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementPath));
```